# python - how to crop image from html page

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, crop

i have this html page with image [image: captcha]

i want to crop only the captcha image, because i can't get the image source

so i want to crop only the captcha image then pass it on my code to extract number from image

here's the code of extract number from image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

im_path="E:/"
im_name = "test.png"

# Read Image and Crop Borders
img = cv2.imread(im_path+im_name)[3:-2, 5:]

# Threshold on Red Channel
th=185
img[img[...,2]>th]=0

# Gray Color
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Thresholding
binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Resize as original image is small 
scale_ = 5 # of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_ )
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_ )
dim = (width, height)
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(binary, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Morhpological Erosion
resized = cv2.erode(resized, None)

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized, config='--psm 13 outputbase digits')

# Visualization
cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("output", resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print(txt)
```

(i got these code from member here named Bilal)

so what i expect is i crop the image from the html page, then passed it on the code above to extract the number from the cropping image

i dont really know how to crop image

Comment: can you mention the URL if it's public?

Comment: Sorry its not public, need to login.

Comment: no problem, see if this is helpful for you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75647253/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-element-and-compare-its-text-content/75647758#75647758

Comment: ah i cant install module ddddocr from that link. i use python 3.11

Comment: I'm not sure about 3.11 but you can install it on python 3.10