# if page requires to input random characters before login, how to automate it using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, selenium-ide

if page requires to input random characters before login, how to automate it using selenium web driver?

For instances, going to a website to input username/password and click login, then a text image appear asking for inputting the random characters generated. But the random characters are on image thus cannot be identified by object selector. How could it be automated?

Regards,

Comment: I think what you are taking about is some kind of captcha which is added to prevent Automation bots, you can read more here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872451/how-can-i-bypass-the-google-captcha-with-selenium-and-python
can you add a screenshot if its something else

Comment: you can capture the  text image by taking its screenshot and can apply OCR to extract the characters on it, input those texts to proceed with the login. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75647253/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-web-element-and-compare-its-text-content/75647758#75647758